# Is the group $G_{n,\phi} = \langle x_1 , \dots, x_n \mid x_i^2, (x_i x_j)^4, x_i x_{\phi(i)} x_{i+1} x_{\phi(i)} \rangle$ abelian?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap, group-presentation, computational-algebra

I am working on a family of finitely presented groups and I asking me the following question. Let $\phi$ be an application from $\left\{1,\dots,n\right\}$ to $\left\{1,\dots,n\right\}$ (not necessary bijective), we consider the group defined by:
$$G_{n,\phi} = \langle x_1 , \dots, x_n \mid x_i^2, (x_i x_j)^4, x_i x_{\phi(i)} x_{i+1} x_{\phi(i)} \rangle. $$
Is $G_{n,\phi}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$?

It is clear that the abelianisation of $G_{n,\phi}$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so the question is equivalent to prove that $G_{n,\phi}$ a monogenous group or an abelian group. Futhermore, we have that $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ commute.

I have tested on GAP the first cases, and it seems to be true when $n\leq 7$. But I don't found a method to simplify this presentation for all $n$ and $\phi$. If you have any idea, it is welcome.

**Edit I:** The question is equivalent to prove that the group $K_{n,\phi}$ is trivial, where:
$$
K_{n,\phi} = \langle y_1,\dots,y_n \mid y_1, (y_i y_j^{-1})^4, y_i y_{\phi(i)}^{-1} y_{i+1} y_{\phi(i)}^{-1} \rangle.
$$
In this group we have the properties $(y_i y_{i+1}^{-1})^2=1$, which implies that the order of $y_2$ and $y_n$ is 2.

**Edit II:** I have tried to simplify the set of relations of $K_{n,\phi}$, and it seems that the groups:
$$
S_{n,\phi}=\langle y_1,\dots,y_n \mid y_1, y_i^4, y_i y_{\phi(i)}^{-1} y_{i+1} y_{\phi(i)}^{-1} \rangle,
$$
is always trivial. I have tested it on GAP for all $\phi$, and all $n\leq7$.
In fact, I have also remarked that the groups:
$$
T_{n,m,\phi}=\langle y_1,\dots,y_n \mid y_1, y_i^{2^m}, y_i y_{\phi(i)}^{-1} y_{i+1} y_{\phi(i)}^{-1} \rangle,
$$
seems to be trivial. Once again, I have checked on GAP for all $\phi$ and all $n\neq 6$ and $m\leq 6$.

It is clear that $T_{n,1,\phi}$ is always trivial and that we have a natural morphism $\psi_m:T_{n,m,\phi}\to T_{n,m-1,\phi}$. For the moment, I do not see how use these last properties.

Comment: It looks as if you could use the last relation to iteratively show that generators are redundant, and thus show the group is cyclic.

Comment: Yes, but the relations $(x_i x_j)^4$ are also fundamental. Indeed, if we change the power 4 to a power 3 or 5, the statement seems to be wrong.

Comment: What are $i$ and $j$ in your initial presentation? Do you mean: "$x_i^2$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$, and the other relations for all $1\leq i < j\leq n$?" (So, in particular the value of $\phi(n)$ is irrelevant?) This is my most likely guess as to what you meant, but before thinking about a problem, it's nice to know what the problem states *precisely* :-).

Comment: I'm sorry if my statement was not clear and/or exact. Nevertheless, it seems you have well understood the relations. They are (i) $\forall 1\leq i \leq n$, $x_i^2$, (ii) $\forall 1 \leq i < j \leq n$, $(x_i x_j^ {-1})^ 4$ and (iii) $\forall 1\leq i \leq n$, $x_i x_{\phi(i)}x_{i+1}x_{\phi(i)}$, where $x_{n+1}$ is identified with $x_1$.